# Replace template element for normal div in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-3.2

I'm trying to use templates without using the `template` tag as this one is not supported in any version of IE.

Instead of this:

```
<template id="component-input-slider">
    <span data-bind="text: display"></span>
</template>
```

I'm trying to use:

```
<div class="hidden" id="component-input-slider">
    <span data-bind="text: display"></span>
</div>
```

And in the 2nd case I'm getting the error: `display is not defined`.

- [Working with templates](http://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/5/)
- [Error without templates](http://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/5/)

What's the best solution for this?

I tried adding `data-bind: if: $data` in the template wrapper and [it seems to work on the reproduction](http://jsfiddle.net/1hz10pkc/6/), but not in my real app.

Comment: To prevent your templates from being bound to your root viewmodel, put them in a `<script type="text/html">` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comment above you can use a script tag to create templates like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <table>
    <tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'table-template'}"></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script id="table-template" type="text/html">
    <!--ko foreach: data-->
        <tr data-bind="data: $data">
            <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
            <td data-bind="text: description"></td>
        </tr>
  <!--/ko-->
</script>
```

Here is a working JSfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/gmbrx2vd/4/